# Creating margins in Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm learning the basics of Bootstrap and I'm stuck when it comes to creating margins. I want to give space between the quote and the thumbnails. I've looked up tutorials and even searched Stack overflow and haven't found a solution. It's as if all the elements are stuck together. Can someone please tell me what I need to do to create a margin? Thanks in advance.

```
<div>
   <h1 class = 'text-center'> Bob Dylan </h1>
   <img width = '80%' class = 'img-responsive center-block' src ="http://www.billboard.com/files/media/bob-dylan-portrait-bw-1966-billboard-1548.jpg" alt = 'Bob Dylan'></img>
   <h3 class = "text-center">". . . he not busy being born is busy dying."</h3>
</div>

<div class = 'row'>
   <div class="col-xs-2">
       <a href = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Dylan_(album)"><img width = "100%" src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/6/60/Bob_Dylan_-_Bob_Dylan.gif/220px-Bob_Dylan_-_Bob_Dylan.gif'></a>
        <p class = 'center-block'> 1962 </p>
   </div>
```

https://codepen.io/jwdwsn/pen/awaGdv

Comment: wrap div around them and give them margins.
And by quotes you mean the years?

Comment: I added divs. Couldn't get that to work.  And by quote, I meant the quote below the image. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: `.center-block{ margin:10px; text-align:center; }` Add this to the CSS and let me know if you need something like this, so I understand more.

Comment: I tried your last suggestion. Nothing happened. And I'm not trying to align any text. I just want to add margins.

Comment: Try giving us a pictorial output. So we can understand what you want as the end product.

Comment: Ok I got it, you need margin between the blocks. right?

Comment: Yes. So, just above the thumbnails I would like some space between that bottom section and the quote and image right above it.

Comment: It's a simple CSS thing, accept my edit and it will be fixed in no time.
I'm stuck with something right now.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, instead create a new class "bottom-margin" that adds the standard margin that you need.

```
.bottom-margin { margin-bottom:30px; }
```

Then add a div after the quote div as below

```
<div class = "row bottom-margin">
   <div class = "col-md-12">
   </div>
 </div>
```

I tried it works.

Hope this  helps.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Though, for some reason it's only working in Codepen and not through Sublime even though I pasted the code from Sublime. Thanks for getting me this far.

Comment: I have used Sublime, sorry :(